# Ado.net data services

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

What is Ado.net data services. Where can i download latest version anf how to use in my asp.net ajax application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.NET Data Services is "a combination of patterns and libraries that enable the creation and consumption of data services for the web" (from [the MS site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc956153.aspx))

Basically it's a framework to simplify the access and update of data via rest-like URLs, with JSon or AtomPub.

It's installed with .NET 3.5 sp1 (look for the System.Data.Services namespace in your GAC)